# I get 1 row affected, 1 warning but I've insert the right values

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a db and I'm trying to add some values in my tables, I have 1 waring with one tab (but the data is stored correctly)
The table is

```
CREATE TABLE MACCHINE(
    id_macchina VARCHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, # M01... M20
    id_upX VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL, #MUL
    descrizione VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    data_acquisto DATE NOT NULL,
    valore DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL);
```

and the value is

```
INSERT INTO MACCHINE
(id_macchina,id_upX, descrizione, data_acquisto, valore)
VALUES
("M01","UP01","SOMETHING", "1994-04-13", "1400000,00");
```

But I get the error

```
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

if I write `SHOW WARNINGS` I get `| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'valore' at row 1`

but why? the numers are just 9 and I've set the limit to 10, but also if I try to INSERT `60,00` I get the same error, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does error occur if `1400000.00` used instead of `"1400000,00"`?

Comment: @Alexander doing that I get  `ERROR 1136 (21S01): Column count doesn't match value count at row 1`

Comment: The [code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76dab3/1) works fine.

Comment: try 1400000.00 instead of 1400000,00 - replace comma with dot

Answer (score 3):

for numeric  values you should use number and not string so you should avoid the quotes  around the number .. using quote you have an implict conversion (firts by float and the as decimal) so you exceed  the limit and you have truncate warning

```
INSERT INTO MACCHINE
(id_macchina,id_upX, descrizione, data_acquisto, valore)
VALUES
("M01","UP01","SOMETHING", "1994-04-13", 1400000.00);
```